# sklearn pipeline: running TfidfVectorizer on full training set before applying TimeSeriesSplit inside GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer, gridsearchcv

I'm sure this is possible but I haven't been able to figure it out.  Give a training dataset using `TimeSeriesSplit` with a `num_split=5`, the splits look like this:

```
[0] : [1]
[0 1] : [2]
[0 1 2] : [3]
[0 1 2 3] : [4]
[0 1 2 3 4] : [5]
```

Problem is for the first couple passes, the `TfidfVectorizer` is working with a nominal amount of vocab/features, and I would like to run that on the entire training set before splitting so that the feature size stays the same for all splits.

Barring that however, does anybody know of a way to, while using `TimeSeriesSplit`, only pass the last two splits in the series?  So instead of all 5 splits, `GridSearchCV` just uses these two:

```
[0 1 2 3] : [4]
[0 1 2 3 4] : [5]
```

This would allow a much better vectorization fit even though it won't be identical between passes-- at least it has a larger portion to work with before validation.

Thanks.

EDIT:

The pipeline I'm using is essentially TfidfVectorizer, and then on to a classifier.  But doing some inspection on the data and features it looks like the data set is being split up before being fed to the TfidVectorizer().  Here's the broad strokes:

```
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5)
pipe = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(), 'rfc', RandomForestClassifier()])
grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, params, cv=tscv, scoring='roc_auc')
```

Comment: What does the actual pipeline you're using look like? The vectorizer should be able to be applied before any splitting

Comment: Edited main post with pipeline info.

Comment: @G.Anderson No, all the steps in the pipeline will only be done after splitting, calling `fit()` on training data and only `transform()` and `predict()` on test data of the split.

Comment: Running TfidfVectorizer on the whole data and then doing the splits is not recommended and will defeat the whole purpose of cross-validation. The other thing however (sending only the last two splits) can be done. Do you want to perform that 2-fold validation?

Comment: Cross validation using supersets is already "kind of" defeating the purpose.  At least with normal CV your train/test size is identical every iteration, but using supersets that drastically change the training set with each iteration in turn drastically changes the number of features TfidfVectorizer can extract.  I can see both sides of the coin.  To answer your other quesiton, yes-- I would like to know how to do that using 2 fold (or 3 or 4, etc) validation only using the last 2, 3, or 4 supersets.  Thanks!

Comment: @VivekKumar Thanks for your replies.  I was able to figure out how to turn off cross validation using a lambda hack but that entirely defeats the purpose of passing CV datasets.  Is your method of passing static indices for CV similar to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010065/how-to-give-gridsearchcv-a-list-of-indicies-for-cross-validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do what I want.  Didn't realize you could essentially just pass cv an iterable.  All you have to do is create a time series split, or whatever splits you want, and pass an iterable containing the indices.  So if you have a 10 item dataset, and you just want the last two time series splits of a `num_split=4`, you would just pass this to cv:

```
cv = [([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7]),
      ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]))
```

In this way you can pass whatever tuple of iterables you want.